# Avoid "authorization code" using Youtube Data API

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I am using Youtube API to create a live stream.
Each Time I execute my code  locally I'm asked to visit this URL :

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=985486464984-7b06sf6.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.readonly&state=OWcSputgc0NQdEH&prompt=consent&access_type=offline` and then enter the authorization Code.

I want to upload this to my server so I will not be able to browse for Code each time

My program is in python .
any help thanks ?

Here is my code for I think it's not useful as my issue is linked to authentication

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    
    # Sample Python code for youtube.liveBroadcasts.insert
    # See instructions for running these code samples locally:
    # https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#python
    
    import os
    
    import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
    import googleapiclient.discovery
    import googleapiclient.errors
    from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
    
    
    
    
    scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]
    
    def main():
        # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
        # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
        os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"
    
        api_service_name = "youtube"
        api_version = "v3"
        client_secrets_file = "client_secret_07607-7kkbsf6.apps.googleusercontent.com.json"
    
        # Get credentials and create an API client
        flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            client_secrets_file, scopes)
        credentials = flow.run_console()
        youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
            api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
    
        request = youtube.liveBroadcasts().insert(
            part="snippet,contentDetails,status",
            body={
              "contentDetails": {
                "enableClosedCaptions": True,
                "enableContentEncryption": True,
                "enableDvr": True,
                "enableEmbed": True,
                "recordFromStart": True,
                "startWithSlate": True
              },
              "snippet": {
                "title": "Didou Test broadcast",
                "scheduledStartTime": "2022-08-17T16:48:09Z",
                "description": "my video description"
              },
              "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "public"
              }
            }
        )
        response = request.execute()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: [mre] read this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: HEre is the entire code but I think not useful as my issue is reagarding authnitication

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution
The URL is executed only once in any browser
the provided code then is injected in the application an that's it. You do it only for the first time and your application can run for ages then , no more things will be requested

Comment: Hello ! I am facing the exact same issue, can you elaborate pls ? 
Did you validate your app in Google API ? When I launch my code locally (`python script.py`) it asks me for the code each time. The script is only expected to run with my personal account.